# How to draw an automata using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

[image]

I am new to TeX and not familiar with TikZ package.

Comment: By help of tikz library `automata`. See page 513 in TikZ manual. And Welcome to SE!

Answer (score 3):

Well, your sketch is specific, so it can be drawn also without TikZ library `automata`.

**1. solution**

With help of libraries `arrows.meta` (for arrows), `decorations.markings` (for put arrows on middle of edge) and `quotes` (for put nodes on edges), you can obtain:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,quotes}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    decoration={markings,
                mark=at position .66 with {\arrow{Stealth[]}}}
                    ]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,0);
    \fill[black] (A) circle  (1mm) (B) circle (1mm);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (A) to [out=45,in=135,"DOT"] (B);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (A) to [out=60,in=120,looseness=2,"DASH"] (B);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out=-135,in=-45,"LETTER SPACE"] (A);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out=-120,in=-60,looseness=2,"WORD SPACE"] (A);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out= 60,in= 30,distance=12mm,"DOT"] (B);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out=-30,in=-60,distance=12mm,"DASH"] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Options `auto` serve for automatic placement edge labels on edge (above/below).

**2. solution**

As stated Herr K- in his comment, the above code can be slightly simplified if `out=<angle>, in=<anfle>` is replaced by  `bend left=<angle>`. With this the  paths connecting coordinates `A` and `B` becomes:

```
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (A) to [bend left=45,"DOT"] (B);
...
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out= 60,in= 30,distance=12mm,"DOT"] (B);
\draw[postaction=decorate]  (B) to [out=-30,in=-60,distance=12mm,"DASH"] (B);
```

**3. solution:**

Further code optimization is obtained by definition of:

```
every edge/.style = {draw, postaction=decorate}
```

Considering both optimizations the code for desired image becomes:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,quotes}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    decoration = {markings,
                  mark=at position .7 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2mm]}}},
every edge/.style = {draw, postaction=decorate}
                    ]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,0);
    \fill[black] (A) circle  (1mm) (B) circle (1mm);
\path   (A) edge [bend left=15,"DOT"]                         (B)
        (A) edge [bend left=15,"DOT"]                         (B)
        (A) edge [bend left=45,looseness=1.5,"DASH"]          (B)
        (B) edge [bend left=15,"LETTER SPACE"]                (A)
        (B) edge [bend left=45,looseness=1.5,"WORD SPACE"]    (A)
        (B) edge [out= 75,in= 15,distance=12mm,"DOT"]         (B)
        (B) edge [out=-75,in=-15,distance=12mm,swap,"DASH"]   (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In comparison with 1. solution here is slightly changed look-out of image (bend angles and looseness are smaller).

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: the `bend left`/`bend right=<angle>` keys would be slightly simpler than `in`/`out`.

Comment: @HerrK. good point! Thank you, I will upgrade my answer with this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative version in plain [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), just for comparison.

[image]

```
prologues:=3;outputtemplate:="%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);

path c, e, a, b; 
c = fullcircle scaled 89; 
e = c yscaled 7/16;
a = point 0 of c {dir 80} 
 .. point 0 of c shifted (21,13) {down}
 .. {dir -170} cycle;
b = a reflectedabout(left,right);

forsuffixes $=e,c:
  drawarrow subpath(6,2) of $; 
  drawarrow subpath(2,-2) of $;
endfor

forsuffixes $=a,b:
  draw $;
  drawarrow subpath (1,1.414) of $;
endfor 

forsuffixes $=0,4:
  fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted point $ of c;
endfor

defaultfont := "ptmr8r";
defaultscale := 0.7;

label.top("DASH", point 2 of c);
label.top("DOT",  point 2 of e);
label.urt("DOT",  point 1 of a);
label.lrt("DASH", point 1 of b);
label.bot("LETTER SPACE", point 6 of e);
label.bot("WORD SPACE",   point 6 of c);

endfig;
end
```